# Vector Calculus Problem on Gradient Cross Product

Tags: vectors, vector-fields

$Problem:$ If a vector function $V=V(x,y,z)$ is not irrotational, show that if there exists a scalar function $g=g(x,y,z)$ such that $gV$ is irrotational, then $$V\cdot (\nabla \times V )=0$$

Remember, $V$ Irrotational $\iff \nabla\times V=0$

My attempt:

Since $\nabla\times V\not=0$, $\nabla\times V$ is a vector that is orthogonal to $V$, and so $V\cdot \nabla\times V=0$ by definition of the dot product.

I am totally unconvinced this can be the answer as nowhere did I use the fact that there exists a scalar function $g$ in my solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: V isn’t irrotational. gV is.

Comment: $V$ not irrotational means $V$ is rotational... did I miss something? @JakeRose

Comment: @JakeRose So what does that tell me?

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/151030/2451

Comment: @KyleKanos  posted it an hour ago and it has6 views, of which 3 are mine. It is an exercise for a physics class anyway, so I tried my luck here!

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Qmechanic

Comment: Math mods: Please merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $g\vec{V}$ is irrotational, $\nabla\times(g\vec{V}) = 0$. Therefore, $\nabla g \times \vec{V} + g\nabla\times\vec{V} = 0$ or $\vec{V} \times \nabla g = g\nabla\times\vec{V}$. Now take the dot product with $\vec{V}$ so that
\begin{equation}
\vec{V}\cdot(\vec{V} \times \nabla g) = g\vec{V} \cdot (\nabla\times\vec{V}).
\end{equation}
The left hand side is zero. Since $g$ is not identically zero, it follows that $\vec{V} \cdot (\nabla\times\vec{V}) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Two things: Why is $g$ not identically zero? And why is the left hand side zero? I appreciate any sort of help I can get :)

Comment: If $g$ is zero, so will be $gV$ and such a function will not be terribly interesting to examine further. Left-hand size is zero because $\vec{V}\cdot(\vec{V} \times \nabla{g}) = (\vec{V} \times \vec{V})\cdot\nabla{g} = 0\cdot\nabla{g} = 0$.

Comment: Thank you! I would upvote but they won't allow it before I have a 15 reputation :P

Comment: Never mind. I am happy that your problems is solved :).